# C# Linq to SQL: Append dates to result query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables: `ItemsSold (itemid, cityid, storeid, soldDate)` and `SupplyDates (cityid, storeid, supplyDate)`

I want to create a chart where Y axis is the number of the Items sold, and the X axis is the dates that the items sold. And this is the code for this:

```
        var itemsSold = from i in dc.ItemsSold
                          where i.cityid == cityid && i.storeid == storeid 
                          group i by i.soldDate.Date into g
                          select new
                          {
                              Day = g.Key.Day + "/" +
                                    g.Key.Month + "/" +
                                    g.Key.Year,
                              Items = g.Count()
                          };
```

But I want to append to the X axis the `SupplyDates` as a mark (without any Y value).

```
var SupplyDates = from sd in dc.SupplyDates
                          where sd.storeid == storeid && sd.cityid == cityid
                          select new { Day = sd.supplyDate, Items = 0 };
```

Comment: What does your code return now? What do you want it to return instead?

Comment: My code now returns the Number of the Items sold and the Day that the items are sold. ({Day: 19/07/2018, Items: 50},{Day: 18/07/2018, Items: 30},....) I want to return something like this ({Day: 19/07/2018, Items: 50},{Day (supplyDate): 19/07/2018, Items: 0},{Day: 18/07/2018, Items: 30},....)

Comment: Do you just want to make an union of the itemsSold and SuppyDates? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatijaHrženjak I want to combine both dates, so if a date exists in both tables then it will appear twice

Answer (score 0):

If the Day and Items properties are of the same type and in the same order for itemsSold and SupplyDates, you can combine them into a new variable:

```
var combinedData = itemsSold.Concat(SupplyDates);
```